# Sending command line arguments from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, SVGFormatException {
    SVG svg = new SVG("test.svg"); //so that the file called test.svg can be called upon
    PortablePixmap ppm = new PortablePixmap(500, 500); //select the size of the pixmap(canvas)

    svg.drawPixmap(ppm); //draw on ppm

    ppm.writeToFile("out.ppm"); //save the file as out.ppm file
```

This is the code I wrote, but I need to get these values from the command line input because if I hard code like this, the user cannot select what values they want to use. Can you please help me how to get these values from command line input?

Answer (score 0):

Command-line arguments are already available to you as the `String []` passed to your `main()` method.

So, if you run your program as

```
java YourProgram test.svg out.ppm
```

You can access these arguments as

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, SVGFormatException {
    SVG svg = new SVG(args[0]); // test.svg
    PortablePixmap ppm = new PortablePixmap(500, 500);

    svg.drawPixmap(ppm); //draw on ppm

    ppm.writeToFile(args[1]); // out.ppm
}
```

Since, you're using Eclipse you would have to go to

> Right-click > Run As > Run configurations > Arguments tab

Add `test.svg out.ppm` under `Program arguments`. Click `Apply` and then `Run`.

Comment: @user2669336 that's explained in the duplicated Q/A, looks that you never checked it.

Answer (score 0):

Click the little arrow next to the `Run` button and select `run configurations -> (x) = arguments` tab and below the `Program arguments:` text box click the `variables` button and have at it.

The next time you run your program, a dialog box will prompt you for the arguments.

Now, within your program, you can handle these arguments by parsing the `String[] args` parameter of the main method.